# JavaScript Google Maps API map isn't displaying?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I've looked at many similar articles and might be missing something obvious, but I've tried just about everything. I've more-or-less copied and pasted code off of W3 schools trying to fix it. 
I used a button on my index.html to get the user's latitude and longitude and display them which works (also this is a school project and that's one of the requirements). Then I also have to get a map of the user's location and display it.
I click my button, I get prompted at the top left window (using Chrome btw) for my location and I say Allow. My coords pop up but not the map. Nothing pops up either, just a huge blank area for where it should be. I'll copy and paste my index.html that has the involved code as well as the loc.js file.
**I also have a key that I got for free from Google but that didn't fix it.**

**Index.html**

```
<script src = "loc.js"></script>

<input type ="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocation(); getMap();">
<div id="spot"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEiqN2L1odkK645Il8bBVCDqatth6aZyU&callback=getMap"></script>
<div id="userMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

**loc.js**

```js
function getLocation() {
 var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
 //Using navigator, retrieves the users current location (works better with mobile phones)
    if (navigator.geolocation) { //If the user says no (this prompts the user if they want their location known)
        //then it'll go ahead and retrieve their location, if not prompts error message.
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
    } else { 
        userSpot.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser type.";
    }
}

function showLocation(position) {
 var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
 //Retrieves latitude and longitude using this second function called in the first
    userSpot.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function getMap() {
 var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude; 
 var currPosLng = position.coords.longitude; 
 
 var mapOptions = { 
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
 zoom:12, 
 }; 
 
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("userMap"), mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Okay so I submitted the wrong code, I mean the solution that @Ben John posted was correct. The map worked at the specified latitude and longitude. But I forgot I was supposed to make sure that the map centered on the user's location. That's why I have those variables, so it appears my error has something to do with those variables not working.

Comment: center: new google.maps.LatLng(currPosLat, currPosLng),

Is what I'm trying to accomplish. Also for some reason now the Latitude and Longitude won't display either so that broke somehow. I'm really stressed out over this, it's already late so might as well take my time. getLocation() and getMap() don't seem to be working at all anymore. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed a problem with your code in getMap() function in **loc.js**

The variable "position" is not defined when it goes inside. So it's breaking.

Remove below lines and try again 
`var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude; 
 var currPosLng = position.coords.longitude;`

I tried running your code after that. The map gets displayed.

**EDIT:**

Hello, I saw your comments. I have made a quick and simple way for centering map below. Added a marker as well so that it looks nice :)

**index.html**

```
<script src = "loc.js"></script>

<input type ="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocation()">
<div id="spot"></div>
<div id="userMap" style="width:400px;height:100%;"></div>


<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEiqN2L1odkK645Il8bBVCDqatth6aZyU&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**loc.js**

```
function getLocation() {
    var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
    //Using navigator, retrieves the users current location (works better with mobile phones)
    if (navigator.geolocation) { //If the user says no (this prompts the user if they want their location known)
                                //then it'll go ahead and retrieve their location, if not prompts error message.

     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {      
             currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
             map.setCenter(currentLocation);
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: currentLocation,
               map: map
             });
             showLocation(position);
         });
     }

    } else { 
        userSpot.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser type.";
    }
}

function showLocation(position) {
    var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
    //Retrieves latitude and longitude using this second function called in the first
    userSpot.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function initMap() {

    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('userMap'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
    });
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map
You can refer documentations for APIs if you are stuck somewhere. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

"position" is not defined in getMap() function so you can do this (see below comments):

And first of all remove getMap() call in the input tag.

```
function showLocation(position) {
    var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
    // Save your coords
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    userSpot.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + lon;
    // Pass the coords as a parameter in getMap() function
    getMap(lat, lon)
}

function getMap(lat, lon) {
    // Set the paremeters in mapOptions
    var mapOptions = { 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    zoom:12, 
    }; 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("userMap"), mapOptions);
}
```

Hope I helped you.